# Remove all the events from a calendar in Swift

Tags: swift, events, calendar

Is there a command that can remove all the events from a calendar in Swift?

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post.

Comment: Im disappointed that this got down voted.  I realize he didn't explain what he tried,  but obviously he doesn't know where to start.   Completely legit question in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

Considering you are saving the events in with **`startDate`**,**`endDate`**,**`description`** and a **`title`**

```
var event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                event.title = "Test Title"
                event.startDate = NSDate()
                event.endDate = NSDate()
                event.notes = "This is a note"
                event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: EKSpanThisEvent, error: nil)
```

Then all you need is to do is delete the event as this:

```
  var startDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-60*60*24)
        var endDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3)
        var predicate2 = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: nil)

        println("startDate:\(startDate) endDate:\(endDate)")
        var eV = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate2) as [EKEvent]!

        if eV != nil {
            for i in eV {
                println("Title  \(i.title)" )
                println("stareDate: \(i.startDate)" )
                println("endDate: \(i.endDate)" )
              do{
                (try eventStore.removeEvent(i, span: EKSpan.ThisEvent, commit: true))
                }
                catch let error {
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3 compatible**:

```
func removeAllEventsMatchingPredicate() {
    let startDate = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*(-2))
    let endDate = NSDate().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*7)

    let predicate2 = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate as Date, end: endDate as Date, calendars: nil)

    print("startDate:\(startDate) endDate:\(endDate)")
    let eV = eventStore.events(matching: predicate2) as [EKEvent]!

    if eV != nil {
        for i in eV! {

            do{
                (try eventStore.remove(i, span: EKSpan.thisEvent, commit: true))
            }
            catch let error {
                print("Error removing events: ", error)
            }

        }
    }
}
```